# IDEA crashes after installing plugin haskforce

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried to use Idea as a text editor for my Haskell homework. When I opened .hs file Idea advised me to install a few plugins.

[Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKkKd.png)

After installation warning popped up suggesting me to restart IntelliJ IDEA. Now I can't use it at all. Any time I run Idea, it immediately closes, but stays in task manager.
Reinstallation of Idea doesn't help, still crashes.

What can I do to revive IntelliJ IDEA, ideally without reinstalling Windows xD?

Warning:

```
Plugin 'com.haskforce' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
        com.haskforce.codeInsight.HaskellCompletionCacheLoader
      
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:441)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:380)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.access$registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:58)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:255)
    at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.registerComponents(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectLoadHelper.registerComponents(projectLoader.kt:25)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.prepareProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:270)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.access$prepareProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl$doOpenAsync$1.invoke(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl$doOpenAsync$1.invoke(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$progressRunner$1.apply(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$progressRunner$1.apply(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:71)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:243)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:705)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(ForkJoinPool.java:2984)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:294)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:123)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)
```

Comment: Please try to manually clean plugins folder: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs